# How to perform search across multiple tables with different columns in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to bring Search feature in my Java `Spring` application, where I'll need to search across multiple tables of different data types. What would be the ideal way ? Any keyword for tech stack that I could use ? Here's a shortened problem statement.

```
@Entity
public class Organization{
private String parentOrgName;
private String group;
private String address;
private String pin;
}

@Entity
public class Product {
private String name;
private String description;
private String url;
}
```

I need to create a function that will be accepting searchKeyword parameter, and perform a search based on the string across parentOrg, group, address, pin in Organization entity and name, description in Product entity. Something like

```
private SearchDTO search(String searchQuery){
// Searches different table and most of their columns.

}
```

This is an example. I will need to search across multiple tables like say 4-5. What would be  the optimized way in doing so and the tech stack that can be used in bringing this functionality easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native query:

```
@Query(value = "select id, 'Orgazination' from Organization where ... union select id, 'Product' where ...", nativeQuery = true)
```

This way you can retrive the data to reach the full entity data.

You can also index the entity using MongoDB, Lucene, Elasticsearch...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Considering both are disjoint tables and have no relation between will Union work ?

Comment: You will receive the table name and id of the row. After this you can run a `select * from <tableName> where id = <id>` to load the full entity. Considering JPA a interface to SQL, first you need acquire what you expect using SQL. And I think you can't because your result are a matrix with unknown sizes and types. SQL is not built for that. Maybe you should think some workaround using NoSQL or an index framework like Lucene.